# Restore loki from kubernetes persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

We have deployed loki using helm chart. I have the loki persistent volume. How can I figure out what was the schema config used so that I can retain the logs.
Chart loki-2.1.1
Below is the value.yaml

```
  auth_enabled: false
  limits_config:
    enforce_metric_name: false
    reject_old_samples: true
    reject_old_samples_max_age: 240h
  schema_config:
    configs:
    - from: 2018-04-15
      store: boltdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v9
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 240h

livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /ready
    port: http-metrics
  initialDelaySeconds: 45
persistence:
  existingClaim: loki-pvc

podAnnotations:
  prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
  prometheus.io/port: "http-metrics"

podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /ready
    port: http-metrics
  initialDelaySeconds: 45
```

Using a pvc in aws. Size=50GB
I updated the configuratation. When I run it I see the below error in loki pod.

```
level=info ts=2022-02-04T16:59:27.774860964Z caller=main.go:128 msg="Starting Loki" version="(version=2.0.0, branch=HEAD, revision=6978ee5d7)"
level=info ts=2022-02-04T16:59:27.774989475Z caller=modules.go:420 msg="RulerStorage is not configured in single binary mode and will not be started."
level=info ts=2022-02-04T16:59:27.77613543Z caller=server.go:225 http=[::]:3100 grpc=[::]:9095 msg="server listening on addresses"
level=error ts=2022-02-04T16:59:27.776802209Z caller=log.go:149 msg="error running loki" err="mkdir : no such file or directory\nerror creating index client\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/chunk/storage.NewStore\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/chunk/storage/factory.go:176\ngithub.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).initStore\n\t/src/loki/pkg/loki/modules.go:287\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules.(*Manager).initModule\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules/modules.go:103\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules.(*Manager).InitModuleServices\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules/modules.go:75\ngithub.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run\n\t/src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:204\nmain.main\n\t/src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:130\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1373\nerror initialising module: store\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules.(*Manager).initModule\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules/modules.go:105\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules.(*Manager).InitModuleServices\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules/modules.go:75\ngithub.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run\n\t/src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:204\nmain.main\n\t/src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:130\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1373"
```

Can anyone help me with the below error.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but this seems to be happening when BoltDB storage is used with local filesystem. (The error message says that directory with name "" cannot be created, see `NewBoltDBIndexClient` function at `pkg/storage/chunk/client/local/boltdb_index_client.go:60` in Loki sources.)
Using `boldtb-shipper` as the storage type instead seem to not produce any error. But I could not figure out how to make the logs available for querying. The queries for the respective time range still return empty data set.